# How to prove the Dedekind-identity in Group-Theory?

Tags: group-theory

> (Dedekind identity) Let $G=UV$, where $U$ and $V$ are subgroups of $G$. Then every subgroup $H$ satisfying $U\leq H \leq G$ admits the factorization
> $H=U(V \cap H)$.

I have found the proof stated as:

> Every coset of $U$ in $G$ and thus every coset of $U$ in $H$ contains an element of $V$.  $\quad\square$

However, I couldn’t write the proof in detail. So I need any suggestions to start the proof.

Source: **Hans Kurzweil, Bernd Stellmacher** (2003). *The Theory of
Finite Groups: An Introduction*.

Comment: Take any element in H and write it as $uv$. What can you say about $v$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- One direction is easy, both $U$ and $V\cap H$ are subgroups of $H$.
- For the other direction, every group element, hence every $h\in H$ can be written as $h=uv$. Use again  $U\le H$, and by group properties conclude that $v\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed proof:

> *Proof.* "$\subseteq$": Let $z=uv \in UV\cap W$ with $u\in U, v\in V$. Now by right multiplication with $u^{-1}$ on both sides, we get $$v=u^{-1}z$$ and it follows that $v\in W$, because $z\in UV\cap W\in W$ and $u^{-1}\in W$, since by assumption $U\leq W$ holds and for each $u\in W$ the inverse must be in $W$ as well, as $W$ is a subgroup of $G$. From $v\in W$ and $v\in V$ we get $v\in V\cap W$. Therefore we finally have that $z=uv\in U(V\cap W)$.
> "$\supseteq$": If $z\in U(V\cap W)$, then $z=uv$ with $u\in U$ and $v\in V\cap W$. Since $U\leq W$, you have $uv\in W$ and $uv\in UV$, i.e. $z\in UV\cap W$.

Also I found this proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_with_Subgroup_Product_of_Superset

From the Dedekind-Identity we can conclude another nice statement, called *modular identity*.

> If $U \cap V = W \cap V$ and $UV = WV$, then $W=U$.

> *Proof.* With the Dedekind identity we get $$W=WV\cap W=UV\cap W=U(V\cap W)=U(U\cap V)=U.$$

The Dedekind-Identity can also be used to proof the *Zassenhaus butterfly lemma*.